# comparar consulta con array query builder

Tags: laravel, array, querybuilder

hola tengo el siguiente array $consultationsUuid que tiene uuid de consultas medicas cada uuid es una consulta medica quiero compararlos con el la siguiente consulta de la tabla consultation_diagnosis y que me traiga solo los registros que coincidan entre el array y los registros de la tabla consultation_diagnosis

```
public function getAllDiagnosisConsultation($consultationsUuid)
    {
foreach ($consultationsUuid as $uuid) {
    $c =  DB::table('consultation_diagnosis')->select('consultation_uuid', 'diagnosis_date', 'main_diagnosis_id', 'consultation_purpose')->where('consultation_uuid', '=', $uuid)->orderBy('diagnosis_date', 'DESC')->get();
}
            $consultationsDiagnosis = json_decode(json_encode($c), true);
            return $consultationsDiagnosis;
        
    }
```

asi solo me trae un registro como si solo validara una vez.

Comment: El problema es que en cada iteración estás pisando el valor anterior de la variable. De todas maneras no es una buena idea hacer consultas a la bd dentro de un loop pues eso es intenso para la base de datos. Podrías usar `whereIn` y tendrías un código más eficiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la solución va por buen camino, lo que puedes hacer es anidar varios **where** con los datos que vienen en el **array** esto lo puedes hacer guardando los datos dentro de una variable te muestro como lo podrías hacer.

**Ejemplo.**

```
DB::table('consultation_diagnosis')->select('consultation_uuid', 'diagnosis_date', 'main_diagnosis_id', 'consultation_purpose')->where(function ($query) use (consultationsUuid) {
      foreach (consultationsUuid as $uuid) {
          $query->where('consultation_uuid', '=', $uuid);
      }
  })
  ->orderBy('diagnosis_date', 'DESC')->get();
```

Te anexo documentación de Laravel de **Advanced Where Clauses**

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#advanced-where-clauses